# Operating Systems, Memory management

Tags: operating-system

I'm studying OS and I have a doubt about physical and logical addresses.
If logical addresses do not exist in real and are only used to indicate physical addresses, why do we use logical addresses at all? Why not directly physical address?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling 'Logical and physical addresses': 'About 761,000 results'.  VTC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a waste of space on SO and is almost certainly a copy/paste homework dump.

Answer (score 1):

One good example of why an operating system uses a logical address is the concept of virtual memory.  For example, a process can be running in Windows which requires 100MB of RAM to execute.  Without virtual memory, if this amount of RAM were not available, the process could not run.  With virtual memory, the Windows OS can tell the process that the memory it needs is available.  However, the OS cannot expose 100MB of physical memory because it does not exist.  Instead, the OS will expose 100MB of logical memory.  Some or all of this memory may not map to a physical address.  Instead, it might map to disk or another location.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is fragmentation.
Lets say you have 100 MB of memory and the first three processes need 20 MB each. You give them the memory they want, they run and then the second one terminates. You are left with 60 MB of free memory, but any process that wants a sequential address space of 50 MB can't have it.
Using logical addresses gives you that ability.

Answer (score 0):

One of the major benefits of using **logical addresses** (and in fact, similar thinking is true for most **naming abstractions** such as domain names in the networking context, file descriptors, etc.) is that programs can be written in a way that is **agnostic** to the actual layout of physical memory. That is, you can write your program such that data is stored in say, address 0xdeadbeef (this is a logical address), and your program would work just fine (the MMU or a boot loader that performs binary translation would convert the logical address into an appropriate physical address at run-time or at boot time).

In the above scenario, if your program were written to use physical addresses from the get go, you would run the risk of running into conflicts with other processes that use the same address to store data (e.g., other instances of your program).